# Get specialized class from Abstract Factory

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory, abstraction

I have three classes, AbstractContext, ContextA and ContextB that i want to generalize in terms of creation but i want to access the specific methods of each one on different contexts.

AbstractContext:

```
public abstract class AbstractContext {

    public abstract  void  print();
}
```

ContextA:

```
 public class ContextA extends AbstractContext {

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("In context A");
        }

        public void doSomeA(){
            System.out.println("Do some A");
        }
    }
```

ContextB:

```
 public class ContextB extends AbstractContext {

        @Override
        public void print() {

        }

        public void doSomeB(){
            int a=1;
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    }
```

I implemented the abstract factory pattern so i could generalize creation of these classes:

AbstractFactory :

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory {

    public abstract AbstractContext createContext();

}
```

FactoryA:

```
public class FactoryA extends AbstractFactory {

    @Override
    public AbstractContext createContext() {
        AbstractContext newClass = new ContextA();
        return newClass;
    }

}
```

FactoryB

```
public class FactoryB extends AbstractFactory {

    @Override
    public AbstractContext createContext() {
        AbstractContext newClass = new ContextB();
        return newClass;
    }

}
```

FactoryMaker

```
public class FactoryMaker {
    private static AbstractFactory factory = null;

    public static AbstractFactory getFactory(String condition) {
        if (condition == "A") {
            factory = new FactoryA();
        } else {
            factory = new FactoryB();
        }

        return factory;
    }
}
```

The problem here is, after an instance is created, since all factories return the base type i can't access any of the concrete methods of each subclass.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AbstractContext contextA = FactoryMaker.getFactory("A").createContext();
        contextA.print();    //Works fine
        contextA.doSomeA(); //Won't compile

        AbstractContext contextB = FactoryMaker.getFactory("").createContext();
        contextB.print(); //Works fine
        contextB.doSomeB(); //Won't Compile

    }
}
```

On a first attempt, i tried to create methods with the same signature accepting different subtypes of the class, but then i got compile errors since the base type doesn't match the concrete types the methods expect:

```
public static void process(ContextA context){
        context.doSomeA();
}

public static void process(ContextB context){
        context.doSomeB();
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve what i'm trying to do ?

To give you an additional context, i'm creating a Java shared library (API) that will be used by other developers, what i'm trying to do is find a way that developers have the context they want provided in a standard way from my API.
I want them to request a context and work from that point fill the properties that each context has then the api will process the specific parts of each context.

**EDIT:**
It seems i should give you additional details.

Imagine i have two web apps, both web apps access the same services business classes, but may have different business rules because are two different companies.Each company has variations of the same product.

What i'm trying to achive is to make an API that internally will make the heavy lifting and common code for developers.

What i wan't developers to do is tell the api for example the product and company, and the api returns the correct context and initializes the context according to business rules.

I want them to "almost" build just a gui to fill each context i'm returning.
Of course, they will need to know the context they working with to make bindings between the GUI and the context i return, but at the same time, their GUI can have common UI parts.

Updating things on my end too, for now, what i've done is to create a ContextHolder that returns the context that the developer wants, but it doesn't look well because the company can expand the line of products or variations of each product.

I gave as an example different implementations of the abstractContext with different methods, because in each context i will need to access specific properties (in the end will be the same thing, properties are methods returning data). In the end, contexts will just old different sets of data, the common data will stay on the abstractContext class.

I'm trying my best to explain myself, it this is not clear enought please let me know.

Comment: You wrote that "developers don't have to think what kind of context they are creating". But if each context have own specific methods, developers must think about kind of context

Comment: The only way i can see are Generics: Abstract Factory would have the specialized Context as Generic param. The problem with that is, that is the Factorymaker would need a Special Class to create special Factory...

Comment: Alexey, what i want is to my API to provide a generic way to get a context without having each user of my API to create factories on their sides to get the context they want. You're right, they must think about the kind of context, but i want them to have it in a standard way from my api.
What i'm trying to achieve may be impossible :)

Comment: Mikey, something like AbstractContext context=FactoryMaker<ContextIWant>.createContext() ?

Comment: You don't have an abstract factory pattern here, so you might as well stop pretending that you do.

Comment: @Calbertoferreira why can't you have abstract method process in AbstractContext just like print method?

Comment: @Dhruv  Each context has it's unique properties, the common one's will be present on the abstract class. Imagine the API  i'm developing is to process bank loans. Each loan has common data like the person requesting the loan. But depending on the type of loan, you will have to fill additional(specific) information. That's what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @Calbertoferreira why do you want to provide a Factory in the first place ? I mean, why give devs a *thing that can generate things*, rather than provide the thing itself ? Can you describe in more detail how and when other developers will use a `Context`  in the lifecycle of their applications ?

Comment: @guillaume31 I just want to standardize the api and lift as much weight i can from devs. Also, if i provide a factory i can guarantie each context is initialized the same way, and not having the developers to make the different initilization themselvs. Each developer initializes the context the same way.What i'm thinking on something along these lines: 
ContextHolder holder= Factory.getHolder("A");
holder.getHouseLoanContext(); // House Loan Page
Holder.getCarLoanContext(); // Car Loan Page
This way the initialization is the same, then devs can get the context they want.

Comment: But all that doesn't justify the use of a Factory... There's nothing in it you couldn't do with just a `new ContextA()` ! You are either overcomplicating things badly, or you're trying to model something much more complex than your example shows, in which case we won't be able to help you if you don't tell us more about what a `Context` really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the variant:

```
public interface Context {

    void print();

}


public class ContextHolder<T extends Context> {

    private T context;

    public ContextHolder(T context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public T getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void print() {
        context.print();
    }

    public void foo() {

    }

}


public class ContextA implements Context {

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("In context A");
    }

    public void doSomeA() {
        System.out.println("Do some A");
    }
}


public class ContextB implements Context {

    @Override
    public void print() {

    }

    public void doSomeB() {
        int a = 1;
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractFactory<T extends Context> {

    public abstract ContextHolder<T> createContext();

}

public class FactoryA extends AbstractFactory<ContextA> {

    @Override
    public ContextHolder<ContextA> createContext() {
        return new ContextHolder<ContextA>(new ContextA());
    }

}

public class FactoryB extends AbstractFactory<ContextB> {

    @Override
    public ContextHolder<ContextB> createContext() {
        return new ContextHolder<ContextB>(new ContextB());
    }

}

public class FactoryMaker {

    private static AbstractFactory factory = null;

    public static AbstractFactory getFactory(String condition) {
        if (condition == "A") {
            factory = new FactoryA();
        } else {
            factory = new FactoryB();
        }

        return factory;
    }
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContextHolder<ContextA> contextHolderA = FactoryMaker.getFactory("A").createContext();
        contextHolderA.print();    
        contextHolderA.getContext().doSomeA();

        ContextHolder<ContextB> contextHolderB = FactoryMaker.getFactory("").createContext();
        contextHolderB.print(); 
        contextHolderB.getContext().doSomeB();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a design problem. The factory returns an `AbstractContext`, but obviously this type is not enough for clients. I would suggest to either re-think the `AbstractContext` API or introduce an interface. In both cases you must find an abstract api for both contexts.

Otherwise .... If you can't go that way you must reconstitute the lost type information by either use a

- [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)
- Adapter Pattern

**Visitor Pattern approach**

```
 public interface ContextVisitor {
       public void visit(ContextA contextA);
       public void visit(ContextB contextB);
 }

public abstract class AbstractContext {
    public abstract  void  print();
    public abstract void accept(ContextVisitor contextVisitor);
}

public class ContextA extends AbstractContext {
   ....
   public void accept(ContextVisitor contextVisitor){
       contextVisitor.visit(this);
   }
}
```

pattern usage

```
 ContextVisitor cv = new ContextVisitor(){

   public void visit(ContextA contextA){
       contextA.print();  
       contextA.doSomeA(); 
   }

   public void visit(ContextB contextB){
       contextB.print();
       contextB.doSomeB(); 
   }

 }

 AbstractContext contextA = FactoryMaker.getFactory("A").createContext();
 contextA.accept(cv);
 AbstractContext contextB = FactoryMaker.getFactory("").createContext();
 contextB.accept(cv);
```

**Adapter Pattern approach**

```
public abstract class AbstractContext {
    public abstract  void  print();
    public abstract <T extends AbstractContext> T getAdapter(Class<T> type);
}


public class ContextA extends AbstractContext {
   ....
   public <T extends AbstractContext> T getAdapter(Class<T> type) {
       if(type.isInstance(this)){
           return type.cast(this);
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

Adapter pattern usage:

```
 AbstractContext contextA = FactoryMaker.getFactory("A").createContext();
 ContextA contextA = contextA.getAdapter(ContextA.class);
 if(contextA != null){
     contextA.print();  
     contextA.doSomeA(); 
 }
```

If both approaches do not apply to your situation you can only use `instanceof` checks and casts to reconstitute the lost type information. But this is not the preferred way since you move the type selection to client code and it can fast be broken if you change the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you picked a much too complicated tool for the job.

If you just want to *"guarantee each context is initialized the same way, and not having the developers to make the different initilization themselves"*, **encapsulation** is enough.

This basic object-oriented principle allows you to hide implementation details inside an object, which seems to be exactly what you need.

Assuming that `ContextA` still extends `AbstractContext`, compare this (1)

```
ContextA contextA = new ContextA();
contextA.print();   //Works fine
contextA.doSomeA(); //Works fine
```

with your previous code (2)

```
AbstractContext contextA = FactoryMaker.getFactory("A").createContext();
contextA.print();    //Works fine
contextA.doSomeA(); //Won't compile
```

and please tell us what's in (2) that you couldn't achieve with (1), because in the current state of your question and examples, I fail to see it.

Comment: Please ready my updated post. 2 can abstract class initialization, 1 will always initialize the class the same way.

Comment: Err, no. `new ContextA()` will initialize the class in the `ContextA` way, `new ContextB()` in the `ContextB` way, etc.

Comment: besides, I mentioned that `ContextA` still extends `AbstractContext` so you can put shared initialization logic there too if you want.